# Issue in POM.XML? How to resolve this? will there be any issue if this is the setting?

Tags: java, maven

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </plugin>
```

suppose in the pom.xml this is mentioned. But in my eclipse Luna i am having maven 3.2 will there be any problem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you mean: is a 2.3.0 version compatible with a higher version of Maven? There's often no relationship between these versions. Every plugin should describe what it's minimal Maven version is. See http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.openjpa%7Copenjpa-maven-plugin%7C2.3.0%7Cmaven-plugin
It says:

```
<prerequisites>
    <maven>2.0.6</maven>
</prerequisites>
```

That's looking good. Most Maven2 plugins work fine with Maven3. Here's another page worth mentioning: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Plugin+Compatibility+Matrix